# Getting a sum of values in connected pivot field

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am attempting to figure out a good and efficient way to get the sum of a pivot field in a connected table.  I have the following skeleton structure for a Laravel project where users can rent items from a community storeroom.

create_items_table:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->integer('stock')->unsigned();
```

create_people_table:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
```

create_item_person_table:

```
$table->integer('person_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('item_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
```

I then have the following two relationships to define how many of an item a person has rented:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item')->withPivot('quantity');
```

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Person')->withPivot('quantity');
```

I'm looking for an easy way to query the Item model to determine how many of the rentable stock are still available to be rented.  Essentially, "Item.stock" minus a sum of the "quantity" pivot from the join table.  I'm looking to create a custom getAvailableAttribute() on my Item model for ease of access for all of the places I'll need to access it.

I'm pretty familiar with basic/intermediate Laravel but complex subqueries are still a bit beyond my grasp.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Will you need to track late returns for fines? If so how would you track the situation where a person hires 2 of an item and returns 1 a day late and the other a week late? Perhaps if you got rid of the quantity column and create multiple entries in the pivot table instead, then you'd be able to track the return date of each separately and get the quantity currently rented out by using count on the number of people the item has.

Comment: Actually, that's probably true.  I'm making this way harder than it needs to be...

Thanks!